# GWT, Maven, Spring - Getting com.thoughtworks.qdox.parser.ParseException: syntax error on Maven Build

Tags: spring, gwt, maven-2, pom.xml

I am trying to integrate the code from this demo: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-spring-starter-app/ into my main Spring application. I am able to run the gwt-spring-start-app as itself but when I integrate it into an existing Spring app that has a lot of non-GWT classes I am getting the error (on maven build): `com.thoughtworks.qdox.parser.ParseException: syntax error` 
I've spent a while searching on this and seems others have the same problem but I just can't comprehend what they say to do to fix it.. I believe its an issue with the pom and some sort of dependency declaration that shouldn't be there or something but can't figure out what.. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can take a look at the pom below and let me know if you know what could be causing this. Thanks

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.krams.tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hibernate-mysql</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-hibernate-mysql Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>

        <!-- convenience to define GWT version in one place -->
        <gwt.version>2.0.4</gwt.version>
        <spring.version>3.0.4.RELEASE</spring.version>

        <!-- tell the compiler we can use 1.5 -->
        <maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target>

    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- GWT dependencies (from central repo) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.ga</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.14</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>spring-hibernate-mysql</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                            <!-- This will include "gwt:test" during "integration-test" -->
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>gwt-clean</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <servicePattern>**/I*Service.java</servicePattern>
                    <module>${gwt.module}</module>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- If you want to use the target/web.xml file mergewebxml produces, 
                tell the war plugin to use it. Also, exclude what you want from the final 
                artifact here. <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> 
                <configuration> <webXml>target/web.xml</webXml> <warSourceExcludes>.gwt-tmp/**</warSourceExcludes> 
                </configuration> </plugin> -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1-beta-1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>war</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Stack Trace:

```
[INFO] [gwt:generateAsync {execution: default}]
[INFO] using GWT jars from project dependencies : 2.0.4
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] syntax error @[163,64] in file:/home/user/Desktop/JFDemoGWTFork/src/main/java/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.java
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
com.thoughtworks.qdox.parser.ParseException: syntax error @[163,64] in file:/home/user/Desktop/JFDemoGWTFork/src/main/java/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.java
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.parser.impl.Parser.yyerror(Parser.java:987)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.parser.impl.Parser.yyparse(Parser.java:1293)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.parser.impl.Parser.parse(Parser.java:968)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaDocBuilder.addSource(JavaDocBuilder.java:317)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaDocBuilder.addSource(JavaDocBuilder.java:349)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaDocBuilder.addSource(JavaDocBuilder.java:345)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaDocBuilder$2.visitFile(JavaDocBuilder.java:435)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk(DirectoryScanner.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk(DirectoryScanner.java:34)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk(DirectoryScanner.java:34)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk(DirectoryScanner.java:34)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk(DirectoryScanner.java:34)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk(DirectoryScanner.java:34)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.scan(DirectoryScanner.java:52)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaDocBuilder.addSourceTree(JavaDocBuilder.java:432)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaDocBuilder.addSourceTree(JavaDocBuilder.java:421)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GenerateAsyncMojo.createJavaDocBuilder(GenerateAsyncMojo.java:340)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GenerateAsyncMojo.execute(GenerateAsyncMojo.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.forkProjectLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1205)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.forkLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1038)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:643)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Feb 14 13:35:08 MST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/596M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `/home/user/Desktop/JFDemoGWTFork/src/main/java/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.java` is just some apache lib file that I included as source.. from the other posts I found that were sort of for the same issue it seems it will do this for many / all (?) classes that aren't the specific GWT RPC related classes

Comment: Please post the full stack trace for the error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the help, I have posted it

Comment: So it looks like it's having trouble parsing the file /home/user/Desktop/JFDemoGWTFork/src/main/java/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.java during JavaDoc generation. Take a look at line 163 in that file.

Comment: please see recent edit above below stack trace, I don't think the issue is that file, from my research it does this for a lot of files that aren't GWT RPC specific (from other posts I found aboute this issue.. just wasn't able to get a clear sense of how to solve it form those), that is just some lib file and this project was running perfectly fine until I tried to integrate GWT into it

Comment: I found this post which I think is about the same issue but I can't seem to make sense of what they are saying the solution is: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:K0NfAcTlg3AJ:www.zanthan.com/itymbi/archives/002190.html+gwt+com.thoughtworks.qdox.parser.ParseException:+syntax+error&cd=10&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=ubuntu&source=www.google.com

Comment: That post references a very old (and deprecated) GWT plugin for Maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `gwt-maven-plugin` version to `2.1.0-1`.

Comment: awesome, that seems to have solved it.. thanks, I still need to add some additional config info I think for the GWT target so hopefully it will work

Comment: yes it works, thank you, can't emphasize how helpful this was as I was fretting over this for quite a while