# maven-plugin-api com.thoughtworks.qdox.parser.ParseException

Tags: maven-2, annotations

Getting a `com.thoughtworks.qdox.parser.ParseException` when building my project. This error first occurred when I changed:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

to:

```
<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
```

Before that, the entire project built and ran cleanly. maven-plugin-api is the newest version available in maven, so upgrading per "[GWT, Maven, Spring - Getting com.thoughtworks.qdox.parser.ParseException: syntax error on Maven Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996628/gwt-maven-spring-getting-com-thoughtworks-qdox-parser-parseexception-syntax)" won't work. I've also tried downgrading; no change.

The exception:

```
com.thoughtworks.qdox.parser.ParseException: syntax error @[38,1] in file:/home/blablahbla/MyClass.java
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.parser.impl.Parser.yyerror(Parser.java:716)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.parser.impl.Parser.yyparse(Parser.java:826)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.parser.impl.Parser.parse(Parser.java:697)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaDocBuilder.addSource(JavaDocBuilder.java:300)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaDocBuilder.addSource(JavaDocBuilder.java:316)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaDocBuilder.addSource(JavaDocBuilder.java:312)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaDocBuilder$1.visitFile(JavaDocBuilder.java:369)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk(DirectoryScanner.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk(DirectoryScanner.java:34)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk(DirectoryScanner.java:34)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk(DirectoryScanner.java:34)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk(DirectoryScanner.java:34)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk(DirectoryScanner.java:34)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.walk(DirectoryScanner.java:34)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.directorywalker.DirectoryScanner.scan(DirectoryScanner.java:52)
    at com.thoughtworks.qdox.JavaDocBuilder.addSourceTree(JavaDocBuilder.java:366)
    at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.extractor.java.JavaMojoDescriptorExtractor.discoverClasses(JavaMojoDescriptorExtractor.java:628)
    at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.extractor.java.JavaMojoDescriptorExtractor.execute(JavaMojoDescriptorExtractor.java:592)
    at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.scanner.DefaultMojoScanner.populatePluginDescriptor(DefaultMojoScanner.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.plugin.AbstractGeneratorMojo.execute(AbstractGeneratorMojo.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
```

The pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>foobar</artifactId>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <name>foobar</name>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.1.0.M1</org.springframework.version>
        <org.hibernate.version>3.6.0.Final</org.hibernate.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.0-801.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>foo.bar.internal</groupId>
            <artifactId>internal-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The class in question:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
@SecondaryTables({
        @SecondaryTable(name = "MY_TABLE2"),
        @SecondaryTable(name = "MY_TABLE3"),
        @SecondaryTable(name = "MY_TABLE4")
})
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    ...
})
@AttributeOverrides({ // line 37
//        @AttributeOverride( //line 38
//                name = "metadataCheckOutFlag",
//                column = @Column(
//                        name = "COMMENTED_OUT_FIELD",
//                        table = "MY_TABLE2"
//                )
//        ),
})
public class MyClass extends SimpleMyClass {
}
```

All JPA annotations have previously functioned without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out I had an older version of another maven plugin, the `maven-compiler-plugin`. When I upgraded it to versino `2.3.2`, a new version of the qdox library was downloaded and my problems disappeared, even when I tested downgrading to `2.0.2` again. Relevant section of pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```